# How to replace the string value characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have a javascript :

```
var a=camera.getDetails();// (say a=["1","2"] as arraylist/array)                       

var c=new Array(a);  
alert(c);  
window.location="my_details.html?"+c.join(",")+ "_";
```

And in my_details.html :

```
var q=window.location.search;   
alert("qqqqqqqqqqqqq " + q);  
var arrayList = (q)? q.substring(1).split("_"):[];   
//arrayList=arrayList.split("%20");    
var list=new Array(arrayList);    
var s=decodeURIComponent(list).split(",");    
//var str=s.split(",");    
var a=s[5];  
alert("dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaa " + s   + "kkkllll "+ a + "jgkjhgjk"  );
```

I want to remove this `]` character from `s[5]` array value and also `[` character from `s[0]`.

Comment: I don't get it, what is your problem? Please provide proper examples for input and output. I think you should be using JSON to serialize your data and I hope you know that having an array in `foo`, `bar = new Array(foo)` will create a new array with the first element being an array (`foo`).

Comment: When you need to remove the s[5] and s[0] array values.Is there any condition?Can you elaborate your problem?

Comment: in the alert i am trying to display the first array element that is being stored in s. eg: i tried adding var str1=s[0].split("[");
var a=new Array(str1); But still i am not able to get values separately!

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into array only after trimming the braces.

```
var decoded = "[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]";
decoded = decoded.replace(/\[/, "");
decoded = decoded.replace(/\]/, "");
var s = decoded.split(",");
```

See the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/diode/bN3hR/2/